# error: ‘class QComboBox’ has no member named ‘setCurrentText’;

Tags: c++, qt4, qtgui

I have met an error like this,

```
error: ‘class QComboBox’ has no member named ‘setCurrentText’; did you mean ‘currentText’?
             x_cn_num->setCurrentText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "0", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

however, I checked the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcombobox-compat.html), "setCurrentText" is exactly a compatible member of QComboBox.

if you know the real reason and solutions, please give me some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use Qt 3.0 functions. You should be using the alternative functions linked in the documentation (`setItemText` in this case) or if you really want to use the old functions you need to define `QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE` to `0`.

Comment: I followed your instructions, but it doesn't makes sense

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘QComboBox::setItemText(QString)’
         y_cn_num->setItemText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "0", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));

Comment: I sorry. I forget to check the related grammar, I solved this problem now. thank you for your clues.

Comment: Looks like this is a Qt 5.0 function.  I assume when you said Qt 3.0 you meant 5

Comment: @PaulHutchinson `setItemText` is available in Qt 4 which is what the OP was asking about. `setCurrentText` is [deprecated](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcombobox-compat.html)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Looking a little closer you are correct, setCurrentText() is a 3.0 function.  However it isn't available in the 4.8 (at least by default), but is back in 5.0.  This made me think it was added in 5.0, but was instead taken out in 4.8.